# Display Facebook Login Button with php sdk

Tags: javascript, php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

Is there a way to get a default Facebook Login Button when using the fb php sdk? I´m wondering why Facebook is not providing css code to render a default button.

The only thing that I found is the button when using JS.

Maybe there is a way to use the JS button to call the php code on click?

This is the php link that is defined in their documentation:

```
echo '<a href="' . htmlspecialchars($loginUrl) . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
```

[Facebook Login Button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/login-button/)

Answer (score 1):

> Maybe there is a way to use the JS button to call the php code on click?

No, not really.

The button implements the client-side login flow, PHP SDK login is the server-side login flow.

The button renders inside an iframe, so you have no direct styling or scripting access to it in the first place. And trying to attach a click event handler to the iframe element itself is not recommendable either, because that might get detected as potential click-jacking.

> I´m wondering why Facebook is not providing css code to render a default button.

That would have potential to clash with the styles of the host site, so encapsulation would be needed … which would probably mean iframe or something like that again.

Under https://en.facebookbrand.com/ you can get the “f” logo and a few other assets, that can help you build your own. Main colors should be available there somewhere as well.

---

You can of course also use the login button provided by the JS SDK, together with the PHP SDK. They can share cookies, so after you logged the user in on the client, on the next request to your server, the PHP SDK will able to recognize that and pick up the user session.